# imacros keyword verification

Tags: java, firefox, scripting, automation, imacros

I have a macro that auto fills a form. but sometimes after autofilling the form i need to check my email for a link to 'complete filling in the form' (kinda like a verification). sometimes it asks me to check my email for a verification link and sometimes it doesn't.

how can I have my macro check if the page asks me `"you have to check your email"` and if I have to check my email, i want to pause it so I can go look at my mail, and click the verification email. and if it doesn't require me to check email, just loop and start from the beggining and start filling in another form.

Answer (score 0):

there is no if statement in imacros so you need to use javascript (for example) for this.
the example of flow would be:

```
// scrape text on the page
if (text found){
    //pause
    //verify link
}
else {
    continue;
}
```